# how accuracte to use network time protocol for time synchronisation in a LAN

Tags: ntp

I would like to use NTP to synchronise computers in a LAN (100 Mbps bandwidth) to collect data. I hope the time difference between computers after time synchronization can be less than 30ms (the shorter the better) because my data collection sensors collect data in 30 frames per second. Can normal NTP server meet the requirement? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Can normal NTP server meet the requirement?`

Yes. ntp can keep hosts on a LAN synchronized within a millisecond under ideal conditions. 
[Link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)